# Twitter authentication without authorization

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, twitter

I wish to get the tweeter usename of a visitor to my site.

I do not wish to post statuses or access any other information.

I'd be happy to use OAuth, possibly with a 'Sign in with Twitter' button, but this then takes the user to a page which requests authorization for the application, that I wish to avoid.

Is there a way to get the username without authorization?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a text field with popup, like submit your twitter user name here. That will serve your purpose, You can use that name and can read all public tweets made by him.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

This will perform the task, but I wish to avoid this step if the user is already logged into twitter, and log him in if he his not.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: I think to use API(methods which need authentication) you have to authenticate either via API call() or manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
```

instead of

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize
```

as the user authorization endpoint.